# Borel Measurable Function 3

Tags: measure-theory

So the definition of a measurable function is as follows:

Let $f: (X, \mathcal{A}) \rightarrow\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ be a function on the measurable space $(X, \mathcal{A})$. Then $f$ is said to be measurable if $f^{-1}((a, \infty]) \in \mathcal{A}$ i.e. if the pre-image of that interval belongs to the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$

So my question is: do we say $f$ is Borel measurable precisely when $\mathcal{A}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $X$

Comment: Yes, but note that you also need $X$ to be a topological space in order for the Borel sigma algebra (the sigma generated by the open sets) to be defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is the right way to define it, here's the [source (definition)](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Borel_measurable)